# Android google maps v2 mapex overlay

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, heatmap

I have an android google map (v2) that I want to plot a heatmap on. The points that I want to plot consist of hot points and cold points (relative to the default). Does mapex or any other heatmap extension provide support for rendering a heatmap with hot points and cold points?